# using mod_proxy and mod_substitute to replace code in https or redirect

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, proxy, httpd, mod-proxy

I want to setup a free proxy but replace html code in each page in order to display a message/note to user in each visited page.

So far it works ok by this code in httpd.conf:
This code replaces `body` with `body2`

The problem is that if I visit a **https:// url it would not replace the html content**, makes some sense because it should be encrypted.

But if there is no way to replace code in https request, is it possible to configure mod_proxy to redirect all https:// requests to http:// ?

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

<Proxy "*">
</Proxy>


RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding

AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html

Substitute "s|body|body2|i"
```